# passing a variable value using input tag from database using asp code

Tags: input

I'm using  tags to pass some basic data to another site/app but in all the examples I've found the value field is 'fixed' in the code (or selectable from a drop-down) EG value="abcdef". In fact I've already got two such functions in my code but these are sending fixed values.

I'd like to retrieve these values from a database where they have been saved by a previous webpage. I can obviously retrieve these and hold them in local variables in the .aspx code but strugging to find a simple way to pass those values to the  tag eg value=objDatabaseTable.DatabaseTable_FieldA

TIA